# Content description for Menu item - Android

Tags: android, accessibility, menuitem, talkback

I am trying to change accessibility content description for Android menu item.
Here is my code and talk back announcing => Test search, Search, double tap to activate.

```
<item
       android:id="@+id/menuItemSearch"
       android:icon="@drawable/search"
       android:iconTintMode="src_atop"
       android:title="Search"
       android:visible="false"
       app:iconTint="@color/primary"
       app:contentDescription="Test Search"
       app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

How can change it to => Search. Button. Double tap to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Add -> app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuItemSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/icongel_search"
    android:iconTintMode="src_atop"
    android:title="@string/toolbarSearchIcon"
    android:visible="false"
    app:iconTint="@color/primary"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"/>
```

Then

```js
menu.findItem(R.id.menuItemSearch).apply {
                            val searchIcon = this.actionView as ImageButton
                            searchIcon.apply {
                                setImageResource(R.drawable.search)
                                setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primary), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
                                contentDescription = getString(R.string.toolbarSearchIcon)
                                setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent))
                                ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(
                                    this,
                                    object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                                        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View, info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat) {
                                            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
                                            info.addAction(
                                                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(
                                                    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK, getString(R.string.toolbarSearchIcon)
                                                )
                                            )
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Nice answer! I wasn't aware of `actionViewClass` attribute! Glad there is a mechanism for it!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

### 1. Menu items not announcing as a button

You need to import the latest material library in your app's `build.gradle` file.

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'`

Be wary as there may be other dependencies.

### 2. Create a custom action label

Currently this is not possible as you would need to get access to the view in the Toolbar. Then you could use the following method as described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#understandable-actions):

```
ViewCompat.replaceAccessibilityAction(
    // View that contains touch & hold action
    itemView, // <-- this is what we don't have
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_LONG_CLICK,
    // Announcement read by TalkBack to surface this action
    getText(R.string.favorite),
    null
)
```

You could probably raise a bug on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1161519&template=1662302) for problem 2.