# Setting Button Role to the android MenuItem for Android Accessibility

Tags: android, accessibility, menuitem

I am working on the accessibility and currently I want to set the Button Role on the MenuItem. We have checked but not got the proper solution for the same. I tried by setting the custom action layout and then giving the custom action layout Button Role it detect it as button but click need to be handled by setting the click listener on action layout. Which I want to avoid, is there any possibility that we can set role to MenuItem. So it will announce like "Setting Button Double Tap To Activate"

```
`@JvmStatic
    fun View.setCustomRole(roleInfo: String) {
        ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(this,
            object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
                override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
                    v: View,
                    info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
                ) {
                    super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info)
                    info.roleDescription = roleInfo
                }
            })
    }`
```

Tried above method by setting action layout which work but I need to change the click handling from app which I want to avoid.

Comment: It's not clear that you want to achieve. What is that text which talkback have to pronounce?

Comment: @ViacheslavSmityukh suppose I have menuitem on toolbar as Settings so it should announce "Settings Button Double Tap To Activate"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [answered fairly recently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74857476/932052), however I think I can clean it up somewhat.

## Option 1

You can make `MenuItem`'s buttons by default by ensuring you have the latest material library imported.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

The sample app I created for my answer was `1.5.0` and it still had the default "button" announcement.

## Option 2

---

In Material 1.7.0:

- I didn't need any of this code to achieve the solution to the question
- [`onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate#onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(android.view.View,%20android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo)) `host` and `info` are not nullable!

---

Ensure that your `MenuItem` has an [`actionViewClass`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/appbar/action-views#action-view) associated with it.

```
<item
    ...
    android:icon="ICON_REFERENCE"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton"
    ...
/>
```

### Bonus to option 2:

To be able to customize a11y attributes, you can then get the item and assign custom role descriptions or extra actions:

```
// inside onCreateOptionsMenu
val menuActionView = menu
    .findItem(R.id.action_settings)
    .actionView as ImageButton


ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(menuActionView, object: AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
    override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
        host: View?,
        info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat?
    ) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
        
        info?.apply {
            // not required as this is already a button
            // always use a built in class as this will be localized
            //     automatically for you
            // roleDescription = Button::class.java.simpleName 

            // I found I had to set this here, and not in the menu xml
            contentDescription = getString(R.string.action_settings)

            // to replace the term "activate" in "double tap to activate"
            // in production apps, use a localized string!
            addAction(
                AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat(
                    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_CLICK, "Open menu"
                )
            )
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, let me try this out and will update here.

Comment: Yeah please do - sometimes it's very dependent on the particulars of the libraries you are using so it can be difficult to duplicate exact behaviour.

Comment: I have tried as you mentioned, Some points from my side which can help others. Mine material version was lower which I upgraded but one thing that material:1.7.0 requires target sdk v 32+ where mine was 31. So I will need to upgrade to 32+ which is in my roadmap. Also app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageButton" is not required if we use material:1.7.0. BTW Thanks for your detailed answer it added some more insight in accessibility for me.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you're making headway and understanding - I did put a note on the answer itself that in 1.7.0 you don't need `actionViewClass` (see beginning of Option 2), thanks for noticing!